# Pushing to knockout observable array doesn't update select?

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to figure out Knockout, but I can't get the drop down to update after I push a new value to the observable array it's connected to. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Simple example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="js/knockout-3.3.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function ViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.items = ko.observableArray([
          {'id':1,'name':'item #1'},
          {'id':2,'name':'item #2'},
          {'id':3,'name':'item #3'}
        ]);
        self.addItem = function(id, name) {
          self.items().push({'id':id,'name':name});
        };
      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select id="items" 
      data-bind="options: items,
      optionsText: 'name',
      optionsValue: 'id'"></select>
    <script>
      var vm = new ViewModel();
      ko.applyBindings(vm);
      vm.addItem(4, 'item #4');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pushing the item to the underlying array and not to the `observableArray`. To push an item so that Knockout knows that something was pushed you just need to do this: `self.items.push({'id': id, 'name': name});`

Documentation: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html

Comment: Thank you, that does it!